# Unearthing a js php load/execution issue

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Running a base web framework from https://github.com/panique/huge/

The overarching problem I have is: html table needing live updates to account for database (mysql) changes.

Where I'm stuck: I have added to the index/index.php page, the following javascript code to the end of the file (note: header and footers loaded around this index/index.php page) in attempt to refresh the need for updating the table every few seconds in order reload the html table based off of the mysql database state. The index/tableChange module simply gathers the mysql data and returns the query.

```
<?php echo "
  <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    function loadlnk() {
      document.getElementById('tableHolder').innerHTML =
        \"<object type=\"text/html\" data=\"<?php echo config::get('URL'); ?>index/tableChange\"></object>\";
      setTimeout(loadlnk, 3000);
    }
    loadlnk();
  </script>";
?>
```

When I test the index/tableChange snippet out, I am able to load the php by itself in its own individual webpage (but for the purpose of this question, I'm needing to load that content of tableChange into the index/index page).

I also tried adding the $(document).ready(function() { around inside of the script, but this didn't seem to help accomplish anything visible to changing the table.

I looked at what I understood and could find, but I don't think it's a quote issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to remove the inner PHP tags and the echo statement and try like this:

```
<?php

  echo "
  <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    function loadlnk() {
      document.getElementById('tableHolder').innerHTML =
        \"<object type=\"text/html\" data=\"" . config::get('URL') ."index/tableChange\"></object>\";
      setTimeout(loadlnk, 3000);
    }
    loadlnk();
  </script>";

?>
```

I found that I was getting an error in the console, similar to the following:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://localhost/test/target.php does
>   not permit framing.

The solution, at least a quick one in this instance was to add a header before sending the output from `/test/target.php` ~ name `header('X-Frame-Options: sameorigin');` then it worked just fine.

Comment: I tried adding your suggested: header('X-Frame-Options: sameorigin');
However that didn't change anything for me. I had added that to the render() under /application/core/View.php.

Comment: Debunked by not loading the header and footers, so edited the respective webpages to renderWithoutHeaderAndFooter